# Get all DateTime in Action Filter Complex Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need implement a Action Filter to catch all DateTime in the application, the problem is that sometimes the model is complex. For example:

```
public class IngresoOTViewModel
{
    public IngresoOTPreeliminarViewModel InfoOT { get; set; }
    ...
    public string UserNameLog { get; set; }
}
```

*reduced for brevity*

```
public class IngresoOTPreeliminarViewModel
{
    public int? NumeroOT { get; set; }
    ...
    public DateTime? HoraLlamado { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HoraLlegada { get; set; }
    public DateTime HoraAtencion { get; set; }
    public DateTime HoraEntrega { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HoraRetiro { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Firma { get; set; }
}
```

*reduced for brevity*

```
public class DateTimeCustomActionFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter
{    
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var arguments = context.ActionArguments;
        var dateTimeArguments = arguments.Values;
        foreach (var argument in arguments)
        {
            var type = argument.Value?.GetType();
            if(type is null) continue;
            
            if (type == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                var newValue = Convert.ToDateTime(argument.Value).ModifyDateTime(_userService); 
                context.ActionArguments[argument.Key] = newValue;
                continue;
            }

            IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(type.GetProperties())
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)).ToList();
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                
                object propValue = prop.GetValue(argument.Value, null);
                object propType = prop.PropertyType;

                var newValue = ((DateTime)propValue).ModifyDateTime(_userService);
                propValue = newValue;
                    
                continue;
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IngresarOT([FromBody] IngresoOTViewModel ot, bool calculateActividades = false, int? _faenaId = null)
{
*reduced for brevity*
}
```

I need to catch all the DateTime of the model, when the data type comes in the first level there is no problem, but when it comes in inheritance I can't catch it

Comment: "but when it comes in inheritance I can't catch it" What do you mean about this? Could you show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts?

Comment: Hi @QingGuo, what I mean is that when I receive a complex model with a hierarchy, I can only get the DateTimes of the first hierarchical level, in the following hierarchical levels (second, third, etc.) I cannot process the DateTimes   

![_DateTime that if I can capture or process_](https://imgur.com/a/hbEYwYi)  
 `FechaInicio` and `FechaTermino` are DateTime  

![_complex model that I am unable to process or capture DateTime_](https://imgur.com/tQJYKJt)  
Inside `InfoOT` are DateTime